# USB 3.0 causing weird problem for the system

Tags: usb

Currently I am using one Ubuntu system which different types of ports.

```
mine@ubuntu:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:0823 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:0823 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 13d3:3394 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
```

But when I connect the Usb 2.0 or Usb 3.0 device to the Usb 3.0 port then it is causing.
It is acting weird. Here is the output of lsusb when I attach the usb device to the Usb 3.0

```
mine@ubuntu:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8640:800f  
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:0823 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 046d:0823 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
mine@ubuntu:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8640:800f  
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 046d:0823 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
mine@ubuntu:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8640:800f  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I searched on this issue on the Internet but nothing found.
First I thought it might be power issue so I tried with different USB hub but getting the same issue.
Can any one please tell me what is actual issue and solution for it.
Here is my [dmesg log](http://pastebin.com/N06zFih3).